# Looking for a function that can squeeze matrices

Tags: matrix

I am looking for a function that could replace matrices composed of scalar matrices subparts with matrices where those subparts are replaced with numbers.

That is,

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 2 \\
 3 & 0 & 4 & 0 \\
 0 & 3 & 0 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right)\to \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 2 \\
 3 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

That is, an operation inverse to `KroneckerProduct[A, IdentityMatrix[n]]` (which replaces numbers with scalar matrices of order `n`).

The function should look for the best replacement possible, that is the result should be a matrix of minimal possible order.

How to realise this?

Comment: I would look at the paper Van Loan, Charles F. "The ubiquitous Kronecker product." (https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82128039.pdf).  I think it discusses the solution of such of equations.

Answer (score 4):

`BlockMap` and `Tr`.

```
n=2;
A = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
B = KroneckerProduct[A, IdentityMatrix[n]];
BlockMap[Tr, B, {n, n}]/n
```

Comment: And how the code would determine the suitable n?

Comment: The matrices that do not allow such simplification should not be affected, and those which allow several ways should choose the best simplification.

Comment: @Anixx  We needs  an example to illustrate such complex cases.

Comment: Examples: $$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
 9 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$ - your code will squeese it but it should not do anything because it is not composed of scalar matrices;

Comment: $$\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
 3 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$ - needs $n=3$, not $n=2$;

Comment: $$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 5 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 5 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 5 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$ can be simplified to either $\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 5 & 0 \\
 0 & 5 \\
\end{array}
\right)$ or $(5)$. Are these cases complex?

Comment: @Anixx  Edit the original question and add such examples can help other people to read the comple question.

Comment: `squeeze[x_] := SelectFirst[BlockMap[Tr, x, {#, #}]/# & /@ Divisors[Length[x]] // Reverse, KroneckerProduct[#, IdentityMatrix[Length[x]/Length[#]]] == x &]`